# to get all the child count in a gwt tree

Tags: gwt

I am using gwt 2.4
I have a tree widget. I know that getchildcount () method gives the child count. 
In a case where there is a tree with level 1 as the root and suppose I have one level 2 under this root then getchildcount () on level 1 returns 1.

And in another case, if I have a tree with level 1 as the root level and one level 2 as its child. And if this level 2 inturn has level 3 as its child and this level 3 has level 4 as its child.
If I do getchildcount () on level 1 then it still returns count as 1.
Is there any method where I can get the count of all children?  That is, in this case child count of level 1 should return me 3 taking into account the children of level 2?

Hope I am clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) to count all the nodes. That's a depth first [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

```
        import java.util.Stack;

        import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
        import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
        import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
        import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
        import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Tree;
        import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TreeItem;

        public void onModuleLoad() 
        {
          Tree tree = new Tree();
          TreeItem addTextItemRoot = tree.addTextItem("root");

          TreeItem addTextItemLeft = addTextItemRoot.addTextItem("left");
          addTextItemRoot.addItem(addTextItemLeft);

          TreeItem addTextItemRight = addTextItemRoot.addTextItem("right");
          addTextItemRoot.addItem(addTextItemRight);

          TreeItem addTextItemLeft1 = addTextItemRoot.addTextItem("left-1");
          addTextItemRight.addItem(addTextItemLeft1);

          TreeItem addTextItemRight1 = addTextItemRoot.addTextItem("right-1");
          addTextItemRight.addItem(addTextItemRight1);

          Window.alert("count " + dfs(addTextItemRoot));

          RootPanel.get().add(tree);
    }

    int dfs(TreeItem addTextItemRoot)
    {
        int count = 0;

        Stack<TreeItem> stack = new Stack<TreeItem>();
        stack.push(addTextItemRoot);

        while(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            TreeItem pop = stack.pop();

            int childCount = pop.getChildCount();

            for(int i=0;i<childCount;i++)
            {
                TreeItem child = pop.getChild(i);
                stack.push(child);
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this page. What should I do to accept the answer?